# UIButton Scale Animation doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton, cgaffinetransform

Thanks for the help so far !

This is my problem :

I have a method for my animation :

```
-(void) animateButtonDown {

// Animation for cornerRadius
[self.playStopButton setTitle:@"" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
CABasicAnimation *morph = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];
morph.fromValue = @42.5;
morph.toValue = @0;
morph.duration = 0.5;
[self.playStopButton.layer addAnimation:morph forKey:@"morph"];
playStopButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0;

//Animation for scale and color
playStopButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"button" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    playStopButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6,0.6);
    playStopButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGBWithAlpha(0x000000,0.3);
[UIView commitAnimations]; }
```

The animation worked fine. Now the animation for transform the scale factor does not work anymore. It seems like the whole construct :

```
playStopButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
[UIView beginAnimations:@"button" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    playStopButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6,0.6);
    playStopButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGBWithAlpha(0x000000,0.3);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Does not work anymore. It jumps directly to (0.6,0.6)... This was first recognized with update to xCode 6.1.3.

I need a smooth scale transform animation with duration of 0.5.

I hope anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with animation block, may be it will work

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
  playStopButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6,0.6);
  playStopButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGBWithAlpha(0x000000,0.3);
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it doesn´t work. It also jumps from (1.0,1.0) to (0.6,0.6) immediately. I made an extra testproject with just a button and that animation triggered by itself pressed. But it seems that the whole scale animation doesn´t work anymore. It did just fine 2 weeks ago. Could you try to do it in a testproject aswell ? Just to be sure it works and could you please tell me which xCode Version and iOS Version you are using ?